# Multiple backend system with one website

Tags: magento-1.9

I have two physical stores in two different places, only one store is using the magento backend system for the sales. I want to set up another magento backend system for the other store and they will be sharing the same product and the stocks(using the same website).

However, I do not want them to see each other's sales order. Is there any way to do this?

I have seen one method which is
Backend system-->system-->manage stores-->create store. 
Is this the correct way to do?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to create **two websites**, you can share the catalog for the both, but for the access you can't limit the roles per website Magento does not have that natively, So for that you need a customisation or some extension like [Amasty Advanced Permissions](https://amasty.com/magento-advanced-permissions.html)

Good luck.

Comment: Is this extension allow me to create the access which each sale only can view their own team's sales? e.g. store 1 will not be able to see store 2's sales order.

Comment: Yes, I think so, you can try it before buying in Amasty demo extention website